# Complicated mysql query that will sort results from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have to change an existing query and make it sort all results from 2 tables in 1 which is OK but there is something I am not sure if it can be done at all and how the query should look like. 
The problem is that I need to save in the temporary table with the results from both tables the name of specific field from both tables. Plese look at the attached screenshot for better understanding
[image]

I wish the results from both tables to be combined as shown in the Desired table.
So far I have this query

```
SELECT `weddings_objects_lists`.`id`,
```

`weddings_objects_lists`.`object`  as description, 
`weddings_objects_lists`.`date`, 
`weddings_objects_lists`.qty
 FROM 
 `weddings_objects_lists` 
 WHERE `weddings_objects_lists`.`wedding_id`='6'
 union

```
 SELECT `weddings_schedules_lists`.`id`,  

`weddings_schedules_lists`.`schedule` as description,
```

`weddings_schedules_lists`.`date`, 
`weddings_schedules_lists`.qty
 FROM 
 `weddings_schedules_lists` 
 WHERE `weddings_schedules_lists`.`wedding_id`='6'

ORDER BY `date` ASC

[image]

I will really appreciate any help, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(SELECT
    `weddings_objects_lists`.`id`, 
    `weddings_objects_lists`.`object` as description,  
    `weddings_objects_lists`.`date`, 
    `weddings_objects_lists`.`qty`,
    'object' as `type`
FROM `weddings_objects_lists`
WHERE `weddings_objects_lists`.`wedding_id` = '6'
UNION
SELECT 
    `weddings_schedules_lists`.`id`,  
    `weddings_schedules_lists`.`schedule` as `description`, 
    `weddings_schedules_lists`.`date`,
    `weddings_schedules_lists`.`qty`,
    'schedule' as `type`
FROM `weddings_schedules_lists`
WHERE `weddings_schedules_lists`.`wedding_id` = '6')
ORDER BY `date` ASC, `type`
```

You should wrap you union query with parentheses, and use fixed value as type, then do `order by`.

Comment: Man you saved my day :) Thank you, I accept this as working solution in 4 mins, Thank you !